# AttributeError while using python

Tags: python

I am trying to make the following script working, but it doesn't work...
Can someone help me?

```
if happy == "no":
        import csv
        csvbestand='improvements.csv'
        try:
            f = open('improvements.csv', 'w', newline='')
            writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
            data = [(input("What is your name?: ")),
                    (input("What do you want to improve? "))]
            f.writerows(data)
        finally:
            f.close()
```

I do get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/maxva/OneDrive/Documents/HU/HU/Programming/Huiswerk/Week 4/Weekopdracht/test.py", line 31, in <module>
    f.writerows(data)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerows'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Furthermore, is it possible to safe the input everytime when I run the program?
Now, when I run this program, it safe's the input in the CSV file, but the next time when I run it, he deletes the previous data, but I want to keep the previous data as well.

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: [`writer.writerows(data)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)

Comment: `f` has no method `writerows`, `writer` does

Comment: Thanks a lot! And how about the fact that the previous data removes when I run the program again?

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the answers! It worked. But how about the fact that the
>   previous data removes when I run the program again?

Already works! I changed the "w" to an "a" over here:

```
open(csvbestand1, 'a', newline='')
```